# Error with jboss cookie authorizarion

Tags: java, cookies, jboss, war

I'm getting an auth cookie expired error when i try to submit run my web service. It is just me because my colleague is able to run the service fine without any errors. Can you please point wt needs to be changed in the jboss.

```
19:43:20,162 INFO  [com.xxxxx.web.security.netcookieauth.xxxWebAuthenticationProvider] In custom authentication provider
19:43:20,167 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost].[/packageservice].[JerseyAPI]] Servlet.service() for servlet JerseyAPI threw exception: org.springframework.security.authentication.CredentialsExpiredException: Auth cookie has expired
    at com.xxx.web.security.netcookieauth.xxxxWebAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(xxxxWebAuthenticationProvider.java:176) [:]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:156) [:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at com.xxx.web.security.netcookieauth.xxxxWebCookieProcessingFilter.processBackendServiceAuthentification(AcxiomWebCookieProcessingFilter.java:87) [:]
    at com.xxxx.web.security.netcookieauth.xxxxWebCookieProcessingFilter.requiresAuthentication(AcxiomWebCookieProcessingFilter.java:50) [:]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:181) [:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87) [:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:184) [:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:155) [:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) [:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259) [:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:274) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:242) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:181) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.modcluster.catalina.CatalinaContext$RequestListenerValve.event(CatalinaContext.java:285) [:1.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.modcluster.catalina.CatalinaContext$RequestListenerValve.invoke(CatalinaContext.java:261) [:1.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:88) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:100) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:159) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.request.ActiveRequestResponseCacheValve.invoke(ActiveRequestResponseCacheValve.java:53) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:362) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:654) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:951) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [:1.6.0_37]
```

Comment: Are you calling this service from your web browser ? If yes, clear the (cookies) cache and try again

Comment: Yes, I'm calling it from ny webbrowser, but it still gives me the same error even after clearing cookies.